# Deploying AWS Application Load Balancer by Ingress annotations failed. Calico involved

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer, calico

There is EKS Cluster, AWS CNI plugin replaced by **Calico**(the cause of installing Calico [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66764208/avoiding-aws-eks-ips-limitation-per-node/66777202#66777202)). After installing chart by helm I execute `kubectl describe ingress -n my-ns` and see an error:
`...Failed deploy model due to Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "mtargetgroupbinding.elbv2.k8s.aws"...`

My `ingress.yaml`:

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "front.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.14-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
{{- else -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "front.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-0bbd31e479f6211d7, subnet-017bb4e710d71fcc1, subnet-0e8474c825ada2138 # Public Subnets
spec:
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
        {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /hello
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
{{- end }}
```

`service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "front.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "front.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    {{- include "front.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

In the AWS console it seems everything ok, ALB has active status, but following the DNS name failed.

The interesting fact if I replace the Service type with LoadBalancer, Classic Load Balancer will be deployed and will work fine, DNS name works.

I realize that initial information could seem messy and insufficient, but I have no idea what direction to follow to solve the problem. I will be glad to provide all needed details whatever asked and will be appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was resolved by open up security group from cluster to

https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/1828

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).